# .Net OLAP Cube Explorer control with HTML5 mobile compatibility

Tags: html, mobile, olap, business-intelligence, cube

I'm currently looking for control suite that supports mobile business intelligence reporting. The mobile BI site will be a complimentary site for an existing SharePoint BI solution that presents SSRS / PerformancePoint information to the user.

The mobile site should allow users to view pivot grids of information sourced from an OLAP cube as well as normal SQL query results of information. The controls present on the mobile site should be completely compatible with iOS, Android and WinPhone devices as the information will primarily be used on mobile devices by users who are often off-site.

At the moment, the only control suite I can find that seems to fit the bill is the [ComponentArt suite for mobile dashboarding](http://www.componentart.com/services/).

I had a look at Telerik / Infragistics but neither have any native OLAP cube controls.

Does anyone else have any other suggestions that I can investigate?

Thanks,
Brian.

Comment: Look at new Flexmonster Pivot HTML5 release.
http://www.flexmonster.com/Demo/flash-pivot-table-component-demo

Answer (score 0):

We are developing a version of the component [Ranet OLAP](https://bi.galaktikasoft.com/js/RanetOlap/) for HTML5+JQUERY. It will include the MDX designer and the Pivot Grid. A visual user interface will be oriented to work in a web-browser. User interface design for mobile devices on iOS, Android and Windows is discussed. Components will have a common Core for all three platforms: Silverlight, WPF, HTML5.

Comment: Ranet OLAP Mdx Designer on HTML5 Prototype https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyC18ZuXRM0

Comment: Do you have a roadmap/timeframe on when you would have html5 version ready?